# Excel VBA - How to .find a value in a column of merged cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have been trying to use a .find in a column of merged cells to find the top row of the merged area that the value is contained in. The column looks like this.

[image]

using the code

```
 shtfind = BigSht.Range("A:A").Cells.Find("J08").Row
```

or

```
shtfind = BigSht.Range("A:A").mergearea.Cells(1,1).Find("J08").Row
```

but neither of these work.

Please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try a simple MATCH to return the row.

```
dim shtfind  as long
shtfind = application.match("J08", BigSht.Range("A:A"), 0)
debug.print shtfind
```

Comment: Another option: `shtfind = Sheets(1).Columns("A:A").Find(("J08", LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole).Row`

Comment: thanks Jeeped and @JvdV both of these were very helpful.It also turned out that my original code also worked if I Dim them correctly. Also how do I cast a Useful comment vote for JvdV's comment?